# Matching an unknown number of groupings in a regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that can match an unknown number of groupings in PHP.

For example, say I have the string `23434_234_234_234234_234_2342_234`.  I need my match array to contain each grouping.  The number of groupings can range from 1 to potentially infinity.

Yes, I realize this could be done by just chopping up the string and using the underscore as the separator, but this is an exercise in regular expressions, not string manipulation.

Comment: Regex can't do this. You can specify a fixed number of groups, but nothing infinite.

Comment: It is common to do excersices by yourself =)

Comment: @Blender ORLY? Isn't `preg_match_all` supposed for that?

Comment: Yes, I know I'm supposed to do it by myself but time is precious :)  @kirilloid `preg_match_all` is pretty much exactly what I was looking for... I missed it in the PHP docs 0_o.  Throw it in an answer and I'll mark it down.

Comment: @kirilloid: Well, that isn't 100% regex. It's trivial to make a function that does the job, but regex alone can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = '23434_234_234_234234_234_2342_234';
$pattern = '/([0-9]+)/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```